# scp w/ BindAddress

Tags: ssh, mac, scp

Apologies if I get some terminology wrong here, I'm very much not a networking expert.

I have a server on my local network but am connected to a VPN, and to reach the local server via `ssh` on my Mac, I need to use the "Bind Address" option to specify that I want to initiate the request from my LAN IP rather than my VPN IP (e.g., if my local IP is 10.0.0.123, I'd use `ssh -b 10.0.0.123 10.0.0.202` to reach the server at 10.0.0.202).

This works fine.

But I can't get `scp` to work. According to the man page and numerous posts on the Internet, I should be able to use `scp -o BindAddress=10.0.0.123 10.0.0.202:someFile.txt .`, however when I do that, I get the following output:

```
cp: –o: No such file or directory
cp: BindAddress=10.0.0.206: No such file or directory
```

...What's up with that? It looks like the parameters are being passed long to `cp` for some reason, rather than being actually used as `scp` parameters. Is there some different way this works on a Mac? Or is there a different way to transfer files through ssh that'll work?

===

**NOTE**: I'm definitely, absolutely not accidentally typing `cp` instead of `scp` :)

Comment: Just a typo: You typed `cp` instead of `scp`

Comment: @EugenRieck I wish that was the case, alas, it is not. Absolutely definitely typed `scp`.

Comment: @EugenRieck It's remarkably weird. Using `scp` without that `-o` parameter works perfectly normally.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the full command including the output? It's weird that `scp` would return an error that starts with `cp`.

Comment: @mtak In my Debian `scp nonexistent whatever` also returns an error that starts with `cp`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Indeed, you're right. My bad

Comment: scp will invoke "cp" if it thinks you're doing a local-to-local copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`–o` is not `-o`. I can see the difference when I write one under the other:

```
–o    # copied from the question
-o    # proper option with the regular ASCII dash
```

The font your browser is using may or may not let you see it easily. Anyway, `–` you used is not equivalent to `-` you should have used.

```
$ printf %s '–o' | xxd   # from the question
00000000: e280 936f                                ...o
$ printf %s '-o' | xxd   # the right one
00000000: 2d6f                                     -o
$
```

The character you used is [Unicode Character 'EN DASH' (U+2013)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm).

Comment: Yeah, the "-" in the question is a unicode character rather than an ASCII dash. Perhaps you copied/pasted part of the command from somewhere rather than typing it in?

Comment: Good grief! Yes, that's it! I did indeed copy/paste the parameter from elsewhere. Thank you!